# Keep script running after logout

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting

I'm trying to run DiabloMiner, and keep it running after I logout. I try to use `screen`.

So what I do is:

1. login to the host, with `-X` switch. Like: `ssh -X myhost`
2. run `screen`
3. run my script, i.e. `./DiabloMiner-Linux.sh -u my_user -p my_password -dd > log.txt`
4. detach from screen by `Ctrl+A`, then `D`
5. try to logout, by `Ctrl+D`

Then my logout hangs. All I can do is `Ctrl+C`, but then when I login again, I can see by `ps` that DiabloMiner died.

How to run it to survive logout from `myhost`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming DiabloMiner has a GUI which is why you've opted to use the `-X` option.  Screen creates a virtual psuedo-terminal with disconnect and background functionality.  However, the `-X` option tells ssh to tunnel any X11 traffic *back to the host you are on*.  This isn't what you want as when you close the ssh session, you break the X11 traffic causing DiabloMiner to die.

The only way you can keep a GUI application (unless it has a headless mode, which would eliminate the need for `-X` altogether) running on a remote host is to start a remote X server for running the application.  You may want to look into `vncserver` and `vncviewer` for this purpose.

Comment: No, DiabloMiner doesn't have a GUI, but it uses GPU. It makes a lot of computing on a GPU. I'm pretty sure it does it on host machine, because my graphics card on my laptop (which I am ssh'ing from) is not compatibile with it. However, `-X` is necessary for some reason. Without it DiabloMiner throws an exception.

Comment: Maybe I should set `DISPLAY` so it could connect to host X windows, but what should it be set to?

Comment: Perhaps there is no GUI but X11 calls are required?  In this case the above suggestion of using vnc server still applies.  You should be able to run the program inside a vnc server session and disconnect from it.

Comment: I know it's old question, but for the people who land here after searching... For applications using X, xvfb may be your option. In particular, on Ubuntu: `$ sudo apt install xvfb` and then `$ xvfb-run your_program arguments... &`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to research [nohup](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm)  .  It works good when using a console program, like a Java console program.   For an X-window program, things might be different, but I think nohup is the general thing you are looking for.

Also, [gnu screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) might help you as well since it has some nohup features.

Comment: I already tried `screen`, and it didn't work. `nohup` didn't work too.